# Node Googleapis Drive Get File Url With Await

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, google-api

Here is my code;

```
await GoogleDriveService.files.get({
        fileId: id,
        alt: 'media'
    }, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        encoding: null
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            // logger.system.warn(err)
        } else {
            var imageType = response.headers['content-type'];
            var base64 = Buffer(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
            var dataURI = 'data:' + imageType + ';base64,' + base64;
            return dataURI;
        }
    });
```

But await is not working. I'm using inside function and function return `undefined` before `dataURI` veriable. What should I do?

Here is my full function;

```
const uploadImage = async (filePath,name,mimeType) => {
    const response = await GoogleDriveService.files.create({
        requestBody: {
            name,
            mimeType,
        },
        media: {
            mimeType,
            body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        },
    }); 
    
    await GoogleDriveService.files.get({
        fileId: response.data.id,
        alt: 'media'
    }, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        encoding: null
    }, function(err, response) {
        var imageType = response.headers['content-type'];
        var base64 = Buffer(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
        var dataURI = 'data:' + imageType + ';base64,' + base64;
        return dataURI;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is for promises, which are an *alternative* to callback functions. Both are ways to handle asynchronous operations like `files.get`.

You must omit the third argument (the callback function) from the `files.get` call if you want to `await` the result.

```js
var response = await GoogleDriveService.files.get({
  fileId: id,
  alt: 'media'
}, {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  encoding: null
});
var imageType = response.headers['content-type'];
var base64 = Buffer(response.data, 'utf8').toString('base64');
var dataURI = 'data:' + imageType + ';base64,' + base64;
return dataURI;
```